# Get innerHTML of a tag robotframework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am new to robotframework. I have a requirement where I need the innerHTML of a tag. I tried something like this

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath: //div[@id="toast-container"]
${temp_elem} =      Set Variable    xpath: //div[@id="toast-container"]
Log     ${temp_elem}
```

But this is not working. Please help

Comment: see this http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute

Comment: I am trying that, could not found solution

Comment: you have to use Get Element Attribute as you are trying to get innerHTML attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to use the keyword [`Get Element Attribute`](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute), passing the locator to the element, and the target attribute:

```
${inner html}=    Get Element Attribute    xpath://div[@id="toast-container"]    innerHTML
```